# Receive Google call in Asp.net web site

Tags: asp.net, google-voice

I want to receive call in asp.net using any Google service or Google voice service API.

**For example:**
when any body call to my Google number I can receive in G-talk or G-mail, like that I want to exact in asp.net, where I can receive that call in .net and can talk with him/her.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checkout http://gvoicedotnet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I have checked this link, please give me any other tips where i can  get full reference.

Comment: Posting links and 'check this out' messages typically don't make great answers.  Could you elaborate on why that solutions works or how?